# content jumps on zooming out with UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I want help with my UIScrollView sample.

I created a simple program that scrolls and zooms the content (`UIImageView`). It works fine, except that the content frequently disappears to the right-bottom when I try zooming out. But since I set `minimumZoomScale` to 1.0f, it is actually not zooming out, only the content is jumping out of the view. And what is even more weird is that I cannot scroll up after this. Apparently content size is messed up as well.

[image]

The setup I have in my sample code is as in the figure below.

[image]

When I checked the status after (trying) zooming out, I found two wrong things.

- **`_scrollView.contentSize` is 480x360, which should not be smaller than 1000x1000**
- **`_scrollView.bounds` jumped to the top somehow (i.e., `_scrollView.bounds.origin.y` is always 0)**

To cope with the two items above, I added following code in my UIScrollViewDelegate and now it works fine.

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view
{
    if(scrollView == _scrollView && view == _contentView)
    {
        // Setting ivars for scrollViewDidZoom
        _contentOffsetBeforeZoom = _scrollView.contentOffset;
        _scrollViewBoundsBeforeZoom = _scrollView.bounds;
    }
}

- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if(scrollView == _scrollView)
    {
        // If you zoom out, there are cases where ScrollView content size becomes smaller than original,
        // even though minimum zoom scale = 1. In that case, it will mess with the contentOffset as well.
        if(_scrollView.contentSize.width < CONTENT_WIDTH || _scrollView.contentSize.height < CONTENT_HEIGHT)
        {
            _scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(CONTENT_WIDTH, CONTENT_HEIGHT);
            _scrollView.contentOffset = _contentOffsetBeforeZoom;
        }

        // If you zoom out, there are cases where ScrollView bounds goes outsize of contentSize rectangle.
        if(_scrollView.bounds.origin.x + _scrollView.bounds.size.width > _scrollView.contentSize.width ||
           _scrollView.bounds.origin.y + _scrollView.bounds.size.height > _scrollView.contentSize.height)
        {
            _scrollView.bounds = _scrollViewBoundsBeforeZoom;
        }            
    }
}
```

However, does it need to come down to this? This is a very simple sequence, and it is hard to believe that Apple requires us to put this kind of effort. So, my bet is I am missing something here...

Following is my original code. Please help me find what I am doing wrong (or missing something)!

```
#define CONTENT_WIDTH 1000
#define CONTENT_HEIGHT 1000

  >>>> Snip >>>>

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    _scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
    _scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(CONTENT_WIDTH, CONTENT_HEIGHT);
    _scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    _scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 8.0f;
    _scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0f;
    _scrollView.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
    _scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    _scrollView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:_scrollView];

    _contentView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sample.jpg"]]; // sample.jpg is 480x360
    CGPoint center = (CGPoint){_scrollView.contentSize.width / 2, _scrollView.contentSize.height / 2};
    _contentView.center = center;
    [_scrollView addSubview:_contentView];

    _scrollView.contentOffset = (CGPoint) {center.x - _scrollView.bounds.size.width / 2, center.y - _scrollView.bounds.size.height / 2};        
}

- (UIView *) viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if(scrollView == _scrollView)
    {
        return _contentView;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `_contentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;`?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But no, it does not change the situation...

Comment: May I ask why your `contentSize` is 1000x1000?

Comment: @tia Not particular reason. It can be any size as long as it is much bigger than the `_contentView` size. However, if it is too big, the entire `_contentView` disappears completely after trying zooming-in, while with 1000x1000 it disappears partially, thus leaving more hint what is going on.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I created a quick sample project and had the same issue you described using the code you pasted. I don't exactly know what the "proper" way to zoom is in iOS but I found [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content) tutorial which says that you need to recenter your contentView after the scrollView has been zoomed. I would personally expect it to be automatically re-centered given that it is the view you're returning in the viewForZoomingInScrollView delegate method but apparently not.

```
- (void)centerScrollViewContents {
    CGSize boundsSize = _scrollView.bounds.size;
    CGRect contentsFrame = _contentView.frame;

    if (contentsFrame.size.width < boundsSize.width) {
        contentsFrame.origin.x = (boundsSize.width - contentsFrame.size.width) / 2.0f;
    } else {
        contentsFrame.origin.x = 0.0f;
    }

    if (contentsFrame.size.height < boundsSize.height) {
        contentsFrame.origin.y = (boundsSize.height - contentsFrame.size.height) / 2.0f;
    } else {
        contentsFrame.origin.y = 0.0f;
    }

    _contentView.frame = contentsFrame;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    // The scroll view has zoomed, so we need to re-center the contents
    [self centerScrollViewContents];
}
```

The code above is not written by me but is simply copied from the tutorial. I think its pretty straightforward. Also, centring the contentView seems to be a lot more elegant then constantly changing the bounds and content size of the scrollview so give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It makes sense and it worked nicely. 
The only thing in your answer was that `_scrollView.frame` should be `_contentView.frame` in my context. I will edit that part and select as my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this problem using the delegate answer that adjusted the rates after zoom... but then I remembered I was using auto-layout, and just adding constraints for centering horizontally and vertically (in addition to the constraints tying the image to each edge of the scroll view) solved the issue for me without using the delegate methods.

Comment: The question was from frame and struts era, and glad to know that constraints elegantly solves this issue now!

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is having an issue of bouncing when you zooming out resulting background to show, try removing bounces (Bounces Zoom) in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 0):

Olshansk answer in swift 5

```
    func scrollViewDidZoom(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        centerScrollViewContents()
    }
    
    func centerScrollViewContents() {
        let boundsSize = scrollView.bounds.size;
        var contentsFrame = container.frame;

        if (contentsFrame.size.width < boundsSize.width) {
            contentsFrame.origin.x = (boundsSize.width - contentsFrame.size.width) / 2.0;
        } else {
            contentsFrame.origin.x = 0.0;
        }

        if (contentsFrame.size.height < boundsSize.height) {
            contentsFrame.origin.y = (boundsSize.height - contentsFrame.size.height) / 2.0;
        } else {
            contentsFrame.origin.y = 0.0;
        }

        container.frame = contentsFrame;
    }
```